# In r, create a new variable in a dataframe based on lookup table with several potential matching variables

Tags: r, lookup, matching

I want to add a new variable `cnty` to dataset `ANES` based on matches from a lookup table. I have read through a number of related questions on here, tweaking them as well, without success.

I have a survey dataset `ANES` spanning many years. During different time periods, the survey used different codes to identify county of interview. The variables associated with county are named variously `a1` `a2` `b` `c` and `fips`. The `fips` number is what I want to pass to `anes$cnty`. Some observations have entries one of the aforementioned variables, and some have more than one. Some have none and will result in `NA`. There are more than 45,000 obs and many variables but an abridged table looks like this:

```
    ##ANES
    # year   female   educ  marital  partyID  a1    a2   b     c     fips
    # 1958   1        4     1        R        241   NA   NA    NA      NA
    # 1958   0        2     1        R         41   NA   NA    NA      NA
    # 1964   1        1     0        D        NA    NA   571   NA      NA
    # 1968   0        3     1        D        NA    NA   13    71041   NA
    # 1968   0        4     0        D        NA    NA   721   31007   NA
    # 1994   1        1     1        R        NA    NA   NA     NA    13089
```

I also have a lookup table df with 216 counties. It matches `a1, a2, b, c, and fips` with the county name.

```
    # LOOKUP
    #  a1     a2     b      c      fips  
    #  241    41    131   23082    26163
    #  981     NA   571   54041    47081
    #  NA      NA     13   71041    06081
    #  451     NA     721   31007   19013
    #  NA      NA     374    44044   13089
```

What I am interested in is the fips -- each observation in the lookup has a fips. I am looking for code that will create `anes$cnty` variable and pass the `fips` from the lookup to `cnty` based on whatever variable `(a1,a2,b,c,fips)` that the ANES row has.

The desired result:

```
##ANES
    # year   female   educ  marital  partyID  cnty
    # 1958   1        4     1        R        26163
    # 1958   0        2     1        R        26163
    # 1964   1        1     0        D        47081
    # 1968   0        3     1        D        06081        
    # 1968   0        4     0        D        19013
    # 1994   1        1     1        R        13089
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

As noted I have deployed numerous attempts based on suggestions from related questions here, and I'm not getting anywhere. My most recent attempt:

```
    anes$cnty <- ifelse(is.na(anes$a2),  as.character(lookup[match(anes$a2, lookup$a2), 'fips']), 
                        ifelse(is.na(anes$a1), as.character(lookup[match(anes$a1, lookup$a1), 'fips']),
                               ifelse(is.na(anes$b), as.character(lookup[match(anes$b, lookup$b), 'fips']),
                                      ifelse(is.na(anes$c), as.character(lookup[match(anes$c, lookup$c), 'fips']), 
                                             ifelse(is.na(anes$fips), as.character(lookup[match(anes$fips, lookup$fips), 'fips']), anes$cnty )))))
```

Comment: Could you edit your example so that the rows you share of LOOKUP correspond to the rows you share of ANES?

Comment: And is the order of matching important? That is, is it possible that one ANES row will match LOOKUP on, say `b`, but it has a different match on `a1`?

Comment: If there isn't a priority issue, I think you should be able to inner join ANES to LOOKUP on each of the variables, union the results, and de-duplicate.

Comment: @Gregor, yes I will work on that edit. And yes it is possible that a given ANES row will have a variable a1 and another variable, say c, that both correspond to the same county fips. Sometimes no keys will match (there is no county recorded that year), sometimes one key will match, sometimes more than one key will match. I will try the inner join and report.

Comment: Okay, that's good. What I was asking is if it is possible that in a certain ANES row the `a1` value matches one FIPS code in LOOKUP while `c` value matches a different FIPS code, requiring a priority order (maybe `a1` is a better match than `c`).  But it sounds like that is not the case

Comment: No, each observation in ANES corresponds to one county (fips code). There may be one or more variables such a a1 or c with different values but they are just different schemes that translate to the county of the actual interview. Hope that makes sense ;P